# Getting data out of the Azure Cost Centre

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-billing-api

Looking for a method to export data outside of the Azure Cost Centre into a storage account. This can't be done because of network restrictions on a storage account (i.e. firewall rules with selected networks prevents the Azure Cost Centre from exporting data to a storage account).

what is the workaround? Can a datafactory do this instead with APIs? Can an Azure function do this? what are some of the options available?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a datafactory do this instead with APIs?

No, Both Logic App and Azure Data Factory has no connector to Azure Cost Centre.

> Can an Azure function do this?

Yes, you can use function to do this. You can do a Http request to get data from Azure Cost Centre and then upload a file with that data to Storage Blob.

Comment: thank you. I now have to go and learn how to do an api get-request...Any recommendations on good resources to learn this? 

edit: I will start upvoting when I get enough rep...